# Excel VBA - navigate through worksheet using 'next' and 'previous' buttons

Tags: forms, excel, rows, vba

I have an Excel form which reads data from each row of an 80-row worksheet and populates each cell into a textbox.

The code for the initial form is below.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

txtbox_revri_idnum.Text = Worksheets("Risk&Issues").Range("A4").Value
txtbox_revri_projname.Text = Worksheets("Risk&Issues").Range("B4").Value
txtbox_revri_isrefnum.Text = Worksheets("Risk&Issues").Range("C4").Value
txtbox_revri_riskrefnum.Text = Worksheets("Risk&Issues").Range("D4").Value
...
txtbox_revri_projname.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Ideally, what I'd like to do is when the 'next' button is pressed, the next row (A5, B5, C5, D5...) is parsed into an array, and the Range is updated with the next row's data. Conversely, the 'previous' button would go in the reverse direction (A3, B3, C3, D3...). Essentially, I'd like to navigate up and down the worksheet reviewing the entire row with each cell in a new textbox.

I've tried all sorts of combinations of VBA (baring in mind I'm new to VBA although do have some Java and PHP experience). The code I have for my 'next' button current has the code below.

```
Private Sub button_revri_next_Click()

txtbox_revri_idnum.Text = ActiveCell.Next.Text
...
End Sub
```

Thank you... I know you guys are way more smarter than me!

Comment: The `next_Click` handler should increment a variable containing the row number and call a function which reads the cells at that row to populate the textboxes. The `prev_Click` handler should similarly decrement the variable. In the `initialize` function, set the variable and call the populating routine.

Comment: Asking what might be a silly question, but how do I capture the row number in a variable? And then join this to the letter, e.g. B+row_num, C+row_num, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.Offset` to achieve what you want.

**TRIED AND TESTED**

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim rng As Range

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()      
    Set rng = Worksheets("Risk&Issues").Range("A4")

    i = 0: j = 1

    txtbox_revri_idnum.Text = rng.Offset(i).Value
    txtbox_revri_projname.Text = rng.Offset(i, j).Value: j = j + 1
    txtbox_revri_isrefnum.Text = rng.Offset(i, j).Value: j = j + 1
    txtbox_revri_riskrefnum.Text = rng.Offset(i, j).Value: j = j + 1
    '
    '
    txtbox_revri_projname.SetFocus
End Sub

'~~> Next Button
Private Sub button_revri_next_Click()
    i = i + 1: j = 1

    If i > (Sheets("Risk&Issues").Rows.Count - 4) Then
        MsgBox "Max rows Reached"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    txtbox_revri_idnum.Text = rng.Offset(i).Value
    txtbox_revri_projname.Text = rng.Offset(i, j).Value: j = j + 1
    txtbox_revri_isrefnum.Text = rng.Offset(i, j).Value: j = j + 1
    txtbox_revri_riskrefnum.Text = rng.Offset(i, j).Value: j = j + 1
    '
    '  
    txtbox_revri_projname.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Similarly Previous Button

```
'~~> Previous Button
Private Sub button_revri_prev_Click()
    i = i - 1: j = 1

    If i < 0 Then
        MsgBox "1st Row Reached"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    txtbox_revri_idnum.Text = rng.Offset(i).Value
    txtbox_revri_projname.Text = rng.Offset(i, j).Value: j = j + 1
    txtbox_revri_isrefnum.Text = rng.Offset(i, j).Value: j = j + 1
    txtbox_revri_riskrefnum.Text = rng.Offset(i, j).Value: j = j + 1
    '
    '  
    txtbox_revri_projname.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: In implementing the previous button I assumed the operator would be '-' over the 'next' operator being '+'. However, in doing this I get the following error message:

Run time error '1004'
Application-defined or object-defined error

The debug points to the last line of code:

    Private Sub button_revri_prev_Click()

    i = i - 1: j = 1

    txtbox_revri_idnum.Text = rng.Offset(i).Value
    txtbox_revri_projname.Text = rng.Offset(i, j).Value: j = j - 1
    txtbox_revri_isrefnum.Text = rng.Offset(i, j).Value: j = j - 1
    txtbox_revri_riskrefnum.Text = rng.Offset(i, j).Value: j = j - 1

Comment: That was an example :) I have updated the code above to reflect those changes.

Comment: Thank you ever so much, could you please let me know what changes I should make to my code, and i'll try again.

Comment: It's the same code that I gave which is based on your post 1 code.

Comment: Thank you - the navigation buttons work!
A related question, when I have cell populating textboxes, and I make changes to those textboxes, I'd like to press an 'update' button which would update the cells with new contents in the textboxes...

The code I have for this is as follows:
ActiveCell.Value = txtbox_revri_projname.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = txtbox_revri_isrefnum.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = txtbox_revri_riskrefnum.Value...

Unfortunately, it populates wherever the currently selected cell is, and not the row that's populating the textbox... can you help please?